# Custom row with Three RadioButtons in a custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, radio-button, android-recyclerview

I have a custom row which have 3 radio buttons.

If I check some radiobutton and after that scroll my listview loses reference of the radiobuttons and when I comeback the radiobutton is not checked.
OR
when I scroll the last radiobutton is checked (but I didn't click in the radiobutton of this row)

Here is the code

**ADAPTER**

```
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;
        if (row == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            row = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.linha_ficha,parent,false);
            holder.tv_linhaFicha_NumItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_linhaFicha_NumItem);
            holder.tv_linhaFicha_Pergunta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_linhaFicha_Pergunta);
            holder.tv_linhaFicha_Tolerancia = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_linhaFicha_Tolerancia);
            holder.tv_linhaFicha_DataAprovado = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_linhaFicha_DataAprovado);
            holder.tv_linhaFicha_DataReprovado = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_linhaFicha_DataReprovado);
            holder.tv_linhaFicha_Responsavel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_linhaFicha_Responsavel);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_O = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.rb_linhaFicha_O);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_X = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.rb_linhaFicha_X);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_X.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

        itensCondicoes = (Fvs_ItemCondicao) getItem(position);

        holder.tv_linhaFicha_NumItem.setText(itensCondicoes.getNumItem());
        holder.tv_linhaFicha_Pergunta.setText(itensCondicoes.getNome());
        holder.tv_linhaFicha_Tolerancia.setText(itensCondicoes.getTolerancia());
        holder.tv_linhaFicha_DataAprovado.setText(itensCondicoes.getDataAprovado());
        holder.tv_linhaFicha_DataReprovado.setText(itensCondicoes.getDataReprovado());
        holder.tv_linhaFicha_Responsavel.setText(itensCondicoes.getNomeUsuario());

        if (itensCondicoes.getResposta().length() > 0) {
            if (itensCondicoes.getResposta().equals("o")) {
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_X.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_x);
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_o_atv);
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_reinspecao_inativo);
                setEnabledCheck(holder,false,true,false);
            }

            if (itensCondicoes.getResposta().equals("x")) {
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_X.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_x_atv);
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_o);
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_reinspecao_inativo);
                setEnabledCheck(holder,false,false,false);
            }

            if (itensCondicoes.getResposta().equals("ox")) {
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_X.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_x);
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_o);
                holder.rb_linhaFicha_Reinspecao.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_reinspecao_ativo);
                setEnabledCheck(holder,false,false,true);
            }
        } else {
            setEnabledCheck(holder, true, true, false);
        }

        holder.itensCondicoes = itensCondicoes;

        return row;
    }
```

**OnCheckedChanged**

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Holder tempHolder = ((Holder)((View)buttonView.getParent().getParent()).getTag());

        if (tempHolder != null) {
            if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.rb_linhaFicha_X) {
                if (tempHolder.getItensCondicoes().getStatus() == 1) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        tempHolder.rb_linhaFicha_X.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_x_atv);
                        setConformidadeRegras(tempHolder);
                    } else {
                        tempHolder.rb_linhaFicha_X.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_x);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.rb_linhaFicha_O) {
                if (tempHolder.getItensCondicoes().getStatus() == 1) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        tempHolder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_o_atv);
                        setNaoConformidadeRegras(tempHolder);
                    } else {
                        tempHolder.rb_linhaFicha_O.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.bt_o);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**And here is the custom row**

[image: RadioButtons X, O and OX inactive when the button is blue is active]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the adapter is re-using the views. You can either disable that function (highly not recommended) or you can save the checkbox states for each item of the List.

First I'd advise you to create a custom class to hold the 3 states for a single item:

```
public class CheckboxStates {
    boolean check1, check2, check3;

    CheckboxStates(boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3) {
        check1 = b1;
        check2 = b2;
        check3 = b3;
    }
}

List<CheckboxStates> checkboxStates = new ArrayList<CheckboxStates>();
```

Now once you have a count of the ListView items (probably at adapters constructor) you can initialize the states to [false, false, false] (if that's the default).

```
for (int i=0; i<itemCount; i++) {
    checkboxStates.add(new CheckboxStates(false, false, false));
}
```

Finally you are ready to read/set the values in your `getView()`:

```
// Get states for this list item
CheckboxStates states = checkboxStates.get(position);

// Get/set the values
states.check1 = false;
states.check2 = true;
states.check3 = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state of the check boxes since the views will be reused and you can't rely on the implicit state stored by the radio boxes.

Add this to the class returned by getItem and on clicking a radio button store the state to that class.